# Is there a way to split a HTML file without losing all the formatting within each segment?

Tags: html, split

So... the [split command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm) allows me to split a file into pieces. The problem with that, though, is that only one of the files is going to contain the HTML headers, and only one of them is going to contain the HTML footers.

(this is probably relevant for a lot of other files that contain header/footer information)

Comment: You're going to need a utility that's specialized to HTML. There are plenty of utilities that generate split HTML files from sources in other markup languages, but it's rare to process HTML files (because the structure is often hard to analyse). Where did you get the HTML files you want split, and what do you want to do with them? There may well be an easier way to do what you want than splitting the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most unix tools, like `split`, are file format agnostic. To split files that use a specific format (like HTML) into smaller validly formatted files, use specific tools. For HTML splitting, `htmldoc` is the first I found looking quickly on the web. It has been packaged (at least in debian, ubuntu, fedora, gentoo, etc…).

Do *not* use `sed`-ish tricks that make troublesome assumptions on the files, as it would backfire one day or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You could first extract and remove the header/footer of the source file, split it and add the extracted header/footer to each split.

You could use `xpath` or `sed` to do the editing of the source file.

For example this command line strips the header footer of a file:

```
$ sed -e '0,/<body>/d' -e '/<\/body>/,$d input.html
```

Where sed is the GNU one and it is assumed that a body tag is on its own line.